# Detect and convert malformed html string to jQuery object

Tags: html, jquery

Working with a system that we don't have the ability to change. It returns some markedup html strings that we convert to jQuery object, manipulate a bit, and then add to the dom of our page.

Sometimes the html string returned is fine and well formed.

```
var str = '<div class="something" id="wrapper"><input type="text" name="name"></div>'
```

More complex than that usually, but you get the basic idea. Well formed, some nested elements etc.

We then use jQuery (the system is older and this is how it was built, we don't want to rework everything to take the $ out) to convert it like so.

```
var $el = $(str);
```

This has worked well for years. Suddenly something broke and we tracked it down to the black box that returns the original markup string. It started doing things like this:

```
<div class="something" id="wrapper" /><input type="text" name="name" /></div>
```

The markup is now being returned with self closing element tags where there shouldn't be any. Again we don't have any access to the code that is generating the markup, so we can't change that.

The self-closing input isn't really a problem; jQuery seems to know to ignore that, but the self-closing div is causing a problem. The div is supposed to wrap the content, but since it is self closing jQuery creates two elements.

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with that is to fix the HTML generation, but in this case you can just replace `/>` by `>` because HTML5 doesn't require an end tag for void elements.

```js
str.replace(/\/>/, ">");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply replace the first `/` after `id="wrapper"` with an empty string, before converting it into a jQuery object like:

```js
var str = '<div class="something" id="wrapper"/><input type="text" name="name"></div>'
var $el = $(str.replace(/\//, ''));
$('body').append($el)
```

```css
#wrapper{ border: 1px solid red; padding:20px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```